# load modules into r-wrapper highcharter

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I'm trying to recreate this [graph](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-symbols/). I'm interested in the labels "Tokyo" and "London" on the right bottom. Apparently I need to source the series-label.js as shown in the html: `<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>`
If you remove that line from the html, the labels are gone.
How can one achieve this with the r-wrapper? I don't care about the sun, snow and colors. Just about the labels on the right.
example code:

```
data(citytemp)

hc <- highchart() %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = citytemp$month) %>% 
  hc_add_series(name = "Tokyo", data = citytemp$tokyo) %>% 
  hc_add_series(name = "London", data = citytemp$london)

hc
```

Answer (score 0):

check this code:

```
library(highcharter)
data(citytemp)
hc <- highchart() %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = citytemp$month) %>% 
  hc_add_series(name = "Tokyo", data = citytemp$tokyo) %>% 
  hc_add_series(name = "London", data = citytemp$london) %>% 
  hc_legend(align = "right", verticalAlign = "bottom",
            layout = "horizental",  y = -5) 

hc
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. But this is just adding a legend. I need it exactly as in the example, in the graph.